# Is there an R function for "Left_Join" but without keeping all combinations of Matches?

Tags: r

I want to match values in a specific column to a different dataframe, and retrieve the entire row of data for only the first match, and not all combinations.

I tried using left_join, but it simply retrieves all the data. Below is an example:

```
# First table
cusip <- c("AAA1", "AAA2","AAA3")
Datecode <- c("201912", "202003", "202006")
FirstTable <- data_frame(cusip,Datecode)


#Lookuptable
cusip <- c("AAA1", "AAA1","AAA2","AAA2","AAA3","AAA3")
Name <- c("Facebook Inc", "Facebook", "Apple","Apple INC", "Amz", "Amazon")
LookupTable <- data_frame(cusip,Name)
```

So What I want is to create a Name column in FirstTable that retrieves the Name from the Lookuptable. But, I don't care whether it says Facebook or Facebook Inc for AAA1.

A simple Left_join keeps all combinations so gives me 6 rows when I only want 3.

Hope that someone can help, Thanks!

- A relatively new user of R

Comment: Prior to your join you could make `LookupTable` unique by `cusip` which by default will keep the first instance of each.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to make it Unique by Cusip, but this function removes all other columns ? Or am I doing something wrong? 

´´´
Lookuptable <- data_frame(unique(Lookuptable$cusip))

´´´

Comment: Try `dplyr::distinct(LookupTable, cusip, .keep_all = T)` using the `dplyr` package or in base R: `LookupTable[!duplicated(cusip),]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fast `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
#make them data.tables
setDT(LookupTable); setDT(FirstTable)
#perform update join
FirstTable[ LookupTable, Name := i.Name, on = .(cusip)]

#    cusip Datecode      Name
# 1:  AAA1   201912  Facebook
# 2:  AAA2   202003 Apple INC
# 3:  AAA3   202006    Amazon
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(FirstTable, 
          LookupTable %>% group_by(cusip) %>% slice(1))

Joining, by = "cusip"
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  cusip Datecode Name        
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>       
1 AAA1  201912   Facebook Inc
2 AAA2  202003   Apple       
3 AAA3  202006   Amz
```